# Post FirstName/LastName to Excel CSV

Tags: php, wordpress, email, post, widget

I currently have a PHP email signup form widget set up to post into an excel csv. The client wanted to add in first name/ last name capture at the last minute.

I can add in the fields, but the data - first name/last name is not appearing in the csv sheet.

Any ideas?

You can see the form at http://kcmediateam.com/barbwebsite/

Comment: To follow up on the comment above, it's easier for people to help if you can isolate the problem to a narrow piece of code and include that in your post, rather than just linking to a webpage.  It'll also make the question more useful for future visitors, since the website might not stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy using [**`fputcsv`**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php), look at my example:

```
// csv file
$csvFile = "csvFile.csv";
// file handler
$fo = fopen($csvFile, "a+");
// http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.fputcsv.php
fputcsv($fo, array(
    'I Am Not',
    'Procrastinating'
));
// always close the handler
fclose($fo);
```